# Will wrapping car battery with insulator help?

Tags: battery

I always park my 2010 Honda CRV outside overnight. My place doesn't get freezing cold (usually around 40 degrees F) and it does get windy.

Will wrapping my car battery with an insulator help extend its life?

Comment: I put a small (500W) heater under the bonnet when it is going to be really cold and use a timer to switch it on for an hour or so. Starts just like a summer’s day then, first flick of the key and it’s a 2.2 litre diesel...

Comment: You know, they make block heaters *specifically for that* @SolarMike - I mean the engine actually has an appropriate site for a block heater *designed into it* and either the OEM or others make block heaters that bolt right into it. It's not a big thing, just 20mm x 80mm or something. It takes less power because it only heats the bits that matter.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica well, I would have to get official approval for a permanent change to the vehicle and my car already has the winter heater option but that only comes online after the engine is running. Some countries control things better (differently) to others and knowing what is acceptable is crucial.;

Answer (score 3):

You have it backwards, battery insulators are used to protect batteries from excess engine heat rather than protect them from cold, as extreme heat is worse for batteries than cold. Car batteries have no heat source, so an insulating blanket is only going to slow heat loss, a car battery sitting overnight will still reach ambient air temperature.

Comment: So about the same as slowing heat getting into the battery - insulation is not concerned with direction but delta T...

Comment: More a case that bottling heat up inside the battery could be bad for the battery.  You wouldn't want to put insulation on an LED light either, it *needs* to get rid of its heat...

Answer (score 1):

Modern fuel injection ,electronic ignition ,should start easily down to about 0 F (outside). So I would not bother with insulation. Insulation will slow cooling but overnight in wind it will cool to about the same temperature ;so, no real difference in battery temperature / voltage. Long ago ,with carburetor and points ignition, I took the battery out and kept it in a warm house overnight ( at 0 F). Next morning ,the battery slowly turned the engine but not enough to start. I see some cars have a little thermal insulation around the battery; That is to protect it from high underhood temperatures and ,hopefully extend life.

Comment: Space before the comma, and no space after, is hard to read. The usual presentation has the comma (or semicolon) immediately after the preceding letter, with the space _after_ the comma (or semicolon).